# Regarding the two flags "Not an answer" being declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

When clicking in "flag" I am getting the message:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please
>   review them before flagging this post!

This correspond to two flags that got declined on last seven days. In both cases I flagged as "Not an answer":

- [Does this cron expression mean every other Sunday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819523/does-this-cron-expression-mean-every-other-sunday/2819858#2819858) (declined 27 Aug)
- [Require Two Header Row in Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102861/require-two-header-row-in-grid-view/10104694#10104694) (declined 20 Aug)

So my question is:

- Why were does flags declined? They do not look as an answer to me.

---

That said, I would like to indicate how useful it would be to have a flag option "convert to comment", not to loose valuable information that is wrongly posted as an answer. I saw this asked not very long ago, but I cannot find the exact question now.

Comment: **If at least 10% of your flags from the past 7 days were declined**. Your total flags has no bearing on this.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled. I wanted to say "In my flagging history of last 7 days".

Comment: Even so - 2 out of 21 is approximately 10% ;)

Comment: Oh so the number is rounded :) Then I rephrase to focus just to the part of why those flags were declined

Comment: @fedorqui, these flags were declined because these answers can be considered as actual answers, or sometimes not, depending on the state of the stock market, the phase of the moon and the amount of beer any given moderator may have had with Shog9 the day before. *(Just kidding, seriously, read [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer))*

Comment: While the first answer is worded as a question, that's just a rhetorical device. It does suggest a solution. I sometimes write things like that as a comment if I'm not confident of it, but it's OK to phrase an answer that way IMHO. The second is a link-only answer, which we generally frown on, but it's still an answer.

Comment: @Barmar good points, thanks for the comment. I also tend to write as a comment if I am not very sure; eventually, I move it to an answer if it was helpful.